# Chrome: HTML form fields with CSS3 background gradient take on parent background colour on focus

Tags: forms, google-chrome, css, gradient

I'm in the process of redesigning a website for a friend from school. Along the way I've encountered a weird bug in Google Chrome: I've styled the contact form (very basic, an `input` each for name and email address and a `textarea` for comments) using a CSS3 gradient background.

Everything works fine – until you click inside a field to enter data, whereupon the name `input` and `textarea` take on the background colour of their parent `form` element. The email `input`, meanwhile, retains the gradient both when focussed and when not (as desired).

Please visit http://www.chrisphilpot.co.uk/lucycooper2012/ to see what I am getting at. As I say, it seems to look fine in Firefox and IE9 picks up on the flat background #FFF which will do for the time being!

Do you have any bright ideas to fix this? I've relinked the page to the full, uncompressed CSS so feel free to have a rummage. The main styles for the form are in: http://www.chrisphilpot.co.uk/lucycooper2012/css/form.css

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Looks good on this end. You using the latest Chrome?

Comment: Looks like it – version 19.0.1084.56. So when you click inside the name and message fields they retain a white (well, grey to white gradient) background? May I ask if you're using a PC or Mac?

Comment: Windows 7, PC, latest Chrome, no extensions. Looks good, background stays put. Try looking at other websites too, copy examples, remove those big ugly headings because they slow your website down bad.

Comment: How bizarre! I am replicating the background colour change (it's very subtle, I'll grant you) on two Windows 7 PCs running Chrome here.

Incidentally, thanks for the heads up about the headings' load time. I've now specified a subset which seems to be making them appear faster. The 'character' and 'style' of the font though has to stay. ;-)

Comment: Thank you all for your help – the problem was stemming from a Chrome extension. I would never have realised without your reassurances as I was sure it would be a bug in my code!

Very happy to call this case closed. :-)